# How to Extract Twitter Mining data of past 4 months

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tweepy

I am tried with following Code but its not giving any info of data.

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
result=[]
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q='elevate_energy',since='2018-11-01',until='2019-02-01',count=400).items(1000):
    result.append(tweet)

def toDataFrame(tweets):
    DataSet = pd.DataFrame()
    DataSet['tweet_text']=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['tweetCreated_at'] = [tweet.created_at for tweet in tweets]
    DataSet['Followers']=[tweet.user.followers_count for tweet in tweets]
    return DataSet

DataSet = toDataFrame(result)
DataSet.tail()
```

But its not giving any info of dataset.
Please send me the code or any references for above problem i am facing.

Comment: can we a sample of what the `result` list looks like?

Comment: ya the result was giving only column names itself.